# Referring collection values in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following code which is referring an image path in xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <system:String x:Key="SomeImage">\\somepath\\someimage.png</system:String>
 </UserControl.Resources>


    <Grid>
    <Image  Source="{Binding Path=VariablePath, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource SomeImage}}" />
    </Grid>
```

Say, I have hundreds of this images in the code. I need this list of images in code for some processing. What I am looking for to have this images defined in a single place and refer in code and XAML

Something like

```
Dictionary <string,string> dict = 
{
       {"SomeImage", "\\somepath\\someimage.png"}, 
        {"SomeImage2", "\\somepath2\\someimage.png"}, 

}
```

In Xaml , to refer the image

```
ConverterParameter={StaticResource dict["SomeImage"]}}"
```

In code

```
foreach(var item in dict)
{
//dosomething
}
```

Hope the requirement is clear. How is it possible to access the labels which is in a collection in both code and xaml is the question.

Alternate ideas are also welcome.

Comment: You could have the Dictionary in your converter, and just pass the key as ConverterParameter.

Comment: The problem is I will have the key used two places. I would like to refer to the dictionary for key

Answer (score 0):

Resources would give you ease of use in xaml but no iteration in code.

An exposed list/dictionary coupled with a converter will do the trick but with worse performances.

Binding to a static Dictionary would be my choice.

You can use it like that in XAML:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static local:YourClass.Images}, Path=Item[SomeImage]}"/>
```

(Assuming your Dictionary is named "Images" and the class in which the Dictionary is is named "YourClass")

Comment: Note that the source is provided by the converter(as actual image) after processing what is in the dictionary.

Comment: @Jimmy Why don't you load the dictionary with imagesource instead of strings? You'll be able to directly bind an image source to the dictionary values without converter

Comment: We keep image in memory and bind directly for performance .Because same source is referred in many places

Comment: @Jimmy I honestly don't understand the issue with this solution. It allows everything you want without downside

Comment: My issue is the "Key". Where is it coming from? I want to refer to it as opposed to define in xaml

Comment: Key is the key of your Dictionary. In your example "SomeImage"

Comment: Exactly. "SomeImage" is declared in xaml as well as in the dictionary. This duplication is what I was trying to avoid. I did resolved it in a different way. I declared a resource file and put key value pairs and referred it in xaml using x:static. Then I read the resource using resource manager and put it in a dictionary. This way the key value definition is in only one place and cannot go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of XAML file is known and predictable, I myself use one of these solutions in situations that I have a lot of user-controls that should be handled in code as a collection:

1- If all of the controls are surrounded by a container like `Grid`, `StackPanel` or etc, Children of container can be retrieved in a loop in a way like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Image> images = new Dictionary<string,Image>();
foreach (var child in container.Children)
{
    if (child is Image)
    {
        images.Add(
            ((Image) child).Name,
            (Image) child);
    }
}
```

2- We can construct the collection of controls in the code and then insert them into the container as a child or content.
As an instance, in the below example we have some ImageBrushes defined as some resources in App.xaml:

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="image_1_key" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/path/to/image1.png" />
<ImageBrush x:Key="image_2_key" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/path/to/image2.png" />
<ImageBrush x:Key="image_3_key" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/path/to/image3.png" />
```

So, we can construct controls based on the resources and then insert them into the container:

```
Dictionary<string, ImageBrush> images = new Dictionary<string, ImageBrush>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    string name = String.Format("image_{0}", i);
    string key = String.Format("image_{0}_key", i);

    images.Add(name, (ImageBrush) App.Current.FindResource(key));
}

((Label) (container.Children[0])).Background = images["image_1"];
```